# How operator == is selected?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, operator-keyword, equality-operator

```
internal static class ChoosingEqOperTest
{
    class A
    {
        public static bool operator ==(A a, A a2) => false;
    }

    class B:A
    {
        public static bool operator ==(B a, B a2) => true;
    }

    static void CheckChosenOper<T>(T x, T x2) where T : A
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x==x2);
    }

    internal static void Do()
    {
        var a  = new A();
        var a2 = new A();
        var b  = new B();
        var b2 = new B();
        CheckChosenOper(a,a2);      // 1. "False"
        CheckChosenOper(b,b2);      // 2. "False" !?
        CheckChosenOper<A>(a,a2);   // 3. "False"
        CheckChosenOper<A>(b, b2);  // 4. "False"
        //CheckChosenOper<B>(a, a2); //Complie Error
        CheckChosenOper<B>(b, b2);  // 5. "False" !?
        Console.WriteLine(a == a2); // 6. "False"
        Console.WriteLine(b == b2); // 7. "True"
        Console.WriteLine(a == b2); // 8. "False"
        Console.WriteLine(b == a2); // 9. "False"
    }
}
```

Some questions:

A) Why #2 & #5 prints "False"? - I expect operator implementation should be taken from `B` class in these cases.

B) Am I right: As both #8 & #9 prints "False" - Cosen operator implementation is the 1st found, both factual-arguments types could be casted to its parameters types?

c) What are common rules of choosing operator == implementation?

Comment: With the generic constraint `where T : A` the function will use the operator from A. If you change it it `where T : B` `CheckChosenOper(b, b2);`  will print `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are using static binding here (static binding is the default, unless you use `dynamic`), so overload resolution occurs at compile time. Therefore, the expression `x==x2` must resolve to either the `==` in `A`, or the one in `B`. It can't resolve it to both. If you look closely at what information the compiler has, you'll notice that it can't resolve it to the one in `B`, because it only knows that `T` is `A` or a subclass thereof. `T` could be `A`, or a sibling of `B`, in which case calling the `B` overload would not work at all. You can't pass an `A` into a `B` parameter, can you?

   You can see your expected result by making your generic method `dynamic` rather than generic:

   ```
    static void CheckChosenOper(dynamic x, dynamic x2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x==x2);
    }
   ```
2. The compiler must resolve to the `A` overload because one of the arguments is `A`, and `A`s cannot be implicitly converted to `B`, so it can't be passed into that parameter.
3. This is all described in the language spec, in a section called [Binary operator overload resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#binary-operator-overload-resolution). But most of it follows the same rules as [method resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#overload-resolution), so you might want to just read that instead.

Comment: 1. Oh, I think I understand - 'cos all ref-types shares single generic implementation, a compiler must choose 1 operator implementation, which will fit all possible cases.

Comment: @user1234567 I don't really know what you mean by "all ref-types shares single generic implementation", but the reason why it must choose only one is because the "choosing" happens at compile time, and there is only one expression - `x==x1`, in your code.

Comment: saying "_all ref-types shares single generic implementation_", I mean, that hypothetically compiler could inspect code & see all usings of this generic method & so it could met `CheckChosenOper<B>` using among others & (hypothetically) could create 1 separate implementation per every met type-argument (like C++ templates). In this case, building implementation for class `B`, it probably would choose operator== from class `B`. BUT! this is the story about hypothetical world, but we live in our real one =)

Answer (score 3):

A) Well, your method `CheckChosenOper` is a generic method, which still "uses" class A as a base class and it's own `==` operator even if you intentionally specify `<B>` type. It seems that operators are not overridden in derived classes, and `CheckChosenOper` method can only work with what is known to it: class A. It cannot go on its own and use reflection to search for other valid equality operators.

B) No, you're wrong. In cases #8 and #9 the compiler has two choices - upcast A to B and compare B1 with B2 and downcast B to A and compare A1 to A2. Since upcasting is a no-no and must be specifically done via casting operator, the compiler goes with the easy A1==A2 choice.

C) Well, if I was writing a `struct`, I'd surely go for one. Along with `!=`, `GetHashCode`, `IEquatable<>`, and some other stuff. But there must be really good reason to create your own struct(s), as they behave differently.